# How to create new div with same existing data?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing a small PHP project. There, I have an invoice module. For that I need an auto-generate option that can generate new div atomically on user click. Here is what I want in new div.

```
<div>
    <select name='pro_name[]' class="pro_name">
    <option value='1'>Pro 1</option>
    <option value='2'>Pro 2</option>
    <option value='3'>Pro 3</option>
    </select>

    <input type='text' name='price[]' class="price">
</div>
```

Please don't ask me to do this by following method.

```
$('#div').append('<div class="cloud"><input type="text" /></div>');
```

My selection box is dynamic and from above example I can't display my dynamic options.

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
<div class='template'>
    <select name='pro_name[]' class="pro_name">
    <option value='1'>Pro 1</option>
    <option value='2'>Pro 2</option>
    <option value='3'>Pro 3</option>
    </select>

    <input type='text' name='price[]' class="price">
</div>
```

Then, you can do something like:

```
var clone = $('div.template').clone();
```

you can now use the variable clone

Comment: Don't forget to do something with that clone: `clone.appendTo("#selector")`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily using the [clone](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) method of jQuery.

```
var clonedDiv;

$(document).ready(function(){
    //Important, if you clone by ID you need to 
    //change the ID before you append the content
    clonedDiv = $('.divToClone').clone();
});

$('#yourTrigger').click(function(){

    //Append the content to the parent div
    $('.parentDiv').append(clonedDiv);
});
```

Also, I recommend you to clone element as soon as jQuery loads to avoid copying user data.

Comment: hey buddy its working but there is one problem. On first click it generate one div but on second its generated 4-5 divs. Please review your code and tell me..

Comment: Solved. That was because you were cloning by class and not by id.

Comment: I'll check it later. Btw plz tell me what will be parentDiv?

Comment: The parentDiv selector refers to the div wich contains all your cloned divs. Normally will be the div above your initial element.

Comment: hey @Vangoso it just generate new div once.

Comment: I think you're making some mistake when you apply my solution. Could you post your code?